# MYySQL is the Table Relationship wrong?

Tags: mysql, database, table-relationships

I'm very new in Databases and more specific in MYSQL. I use xampp + MySQL Workbench.
I make 3 tables using MySQL Workbench:

`- tbStores with fields StoreID(PK-INT-AI), StoreName
 - tbProducts with fields ProductID(PK-INT-AI), ProductName
 - tbProductDetails with fields ProductDetailID(PK-INT-AI), Price, ProductID(FK), StoreID(FK)`

*PK=Primary Key
*INT=Numeric Type Attributes
*AI=Auto Increments

**In case you don’t understand the Relationships above:**

- 1 to many From tbStores(StoreID) To tbProductDetails (StoreID)
- 1 to many From tbProducts(ProductID) To tbProductDetails (ProductID)

I add values to the fields:

`- tbStores=> StoreName=> Store 1
 - tbProducts=> ProductName=> Product 1, Product 2
 - tbProductDetails=> Price=> 50, 30
 - tbProductDetails=> ProductID=> 1, 2
 - tbProductDetails=>  StoreID=> 1, 1`

To the Query:
`SELECT tbStores.StoreName, tbProductDetails.Price, tbProducts.ProductName
FROM tbStores,  tbProductDetails, tbProducts
Where ProductName = 'Product 1';`

**The Problem:**
Query will return this

Store 1, 50, **Product 1**
Store 1, 30, **Product 1**

Is giving me Same Product with 2 different Prices.
What I was expecting to take was this :

Store 1, 50, **Product 1**

What am I doing wrong? I believe it has to do with relationships but I can't figure it out. 
Thanks

Comment: In your `WHERE` clause, you are asking only for Product 1.  It will never show Product 2.

Comment: Yes, later i will have more Stores. So i want to know What Stores have the Product 1 and at what Price. + is no sense relating the prices with 1 product. I edit the Mistake i made with the resaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the tables together (specify how they are related) in the query, the query should look something like this:

```
SELECT tbStores.StoreName, tbProductDetails.Price, tbProducts.ProductName 
FROM tbProductDetails 
JOIN tbStores ON tbStores.StoreID = tbProductDetails.StoreID
JOIN tbProducts ON tbProducts.ProductID = tbProductDetails.ProductID
WHERE tbProducts.ProductName = 'Product 1';
```

If you want all products you have to remove the `where` clause. Note that I took the liberty of changing your implicit joins in the from clause to explicit joins using the `join` keyword.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1eda57/2)

Sample output:

```
| STORENAME | PRICE | PRODUCTNAME |
|-----------|-------|-------------|
|    Store1 |    50 |    Product1 |
```

Comment: You people are amazing, all of you. Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to use `JOIN` combined with `ON`

```
SELECT StoreName, Price, Product Name 
FROM tblStores
JOIN tblProduct ON tblStores.StoreID = tblProducts.StoreID
JOIN tblProductDetails ON tblProduct.ProductID = tblProductDetails.ProductID
WHERE ProductName = 'Product 1'
```

You may consider `GROUP BY` to identify the specific stores.

Comment: I made a mistake to the expecting results. I fixed it now. But when i add more Stores. Is giving For Every Store Each Product with Every Possible Price.